# What are protein iBAQ abundance values in SWATH mass spectrometry?

Tags: proteins, proteomics, mass-spectrometry, mass-spec

I am reading a [journal paper](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fnmol.2018.00364/full#h11) where they used SWATH mass spectrometry to quantify the abundance of proteins in synaptosomes isolated from different species. I am trying to determine whether some proteins of interest are present in synaptosomes.

I have looked at the supplementary material of this paper, and they have a table called *"Protein iBAQ abundance values for discovery proteomics (DDA) measurements of mouse, rat, marmoset and human synaptosomes used for the spectral library."*

I am not very familiar with SWATH mass spectrometry. In the context of SWATH mass spectrometry, what are protein iBAQ abundance values and what do they represent? Would it be correct of me to say that they represent the abundance of a protein present in the synaptosome?

Any insights are appreciated.